# Eclipse Display view and checking if list contains object with some property

Tags: java, eclipse

i have

```
 Class ComplexObject {
      Complex() {}
      public String first;
      public String second;
 }

 List<ComplexObject> allObjects = fillListWithSomeData();
```

Is there some way in Display view to check if allObjects list contains object with field first set to  "foobar" ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this:

```
for (ComplexObject obj : allObjects)
   if (obj.first.equals("foobar")) {
       //we have found one
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a `equals()` and `hashCode()` method implemented in the `ComplexObject` class using the `first` field, you cannot.

Your only option otherwise is to iterate through the list and do a compare on the field value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very generic solution for any type and any type of comparison:

```
public static <T> boolean containsSimilar(T toCompare, List<T> toSearch, Comparator<T> comp) {
   for (T item: toSearch) {
      if (comp.compare(toCompare, item) == 0)
          return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
boolean contains = containsSimilar(lookingFOr, listOfObjects, 
   new Comparator<ComplexObject>() { 
      public int compare(ComplexObject one, ComplexObject two) {
         // your compare logic here
      }
      public boolean equals(Object o) { }
});
```

Where `lookingFor` is a ComplexObject with the properties set to what you want to find, and `listOfObjects` is a list of ComplexObject.